# wxButton won't trigger event.

Tags: c++, events, button, event-handling, wxwidgets

Here's my code. I the IDs are different now but the problem is I can't seem to trigger events when I press the buttons. I'm kinda confused as to why the events won't trigger. It used to work when both ID's were wxID_ANY but both buttons do the same thing when I do that, now, when I declared a new  ID, none of em won't work.

HEADER:

```
#include <vector>
#include <wx/wx.h>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 100;
class determinantsFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    determinantsFrame();
    virtual ~determinantsFrame();

    void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent &event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent &event);
    void OnClose(wxCloseEvent &event);
    void OnCalculateClick(wxCommandEvent &event);
    void OnReset(wxCommandEvent &event);
    double determinant(double matrix[MAX][MAX], int order);

private:

    static const long ID_Calculate;
    static const long ID_Reset;

    wxPanel *MainPanel;
    wxButton *Enter;
    wxButton *Reset;
    wxMenu *fileMenu;
    wxMenu *helpMenu;
    wxMenuBar *menuBar;
    wxTextEntryDialog *td;
    wxString str;
    //vector<double> value;

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};
```

CPP:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "determinantsFrame.h"
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(determinantsFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(wxID_ABOUT, determinantsFrame::OnAbout)
    EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT, determinantsFrame::OnQuit)
    EVT_CLOSE(determinantsFrame::OnClose)
    EVT_BUTTON(ID_Calculate, determinantsFrame::OnCalculateClick)
    EVT_BUTTON(ID_Reset, determinantsFrame::OnReset)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

int n;
wxTextCtrl *numbers[100][100];

const long determinantsFrame::ID_Calculate = wxNewId();
const long determinantsFrame::ID_Reset = wxNewId();

void determinantsFrame::OnClose(wxCloseEvent &event)
{
    exit(1);
}

void determinantsFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    wxString msg;
    msg.Printf(wxT("Hello and welcome to %s"), wxVERSION_STRING);
    wxMessageBox(msg, wxT("About Determinants Calculator"));
}

void determinantsFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    Close();
}

determinantsFrame::~determinantsFrame()
{
    Destroy();
}

determinantsFrame::determinantsFrame() : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, wxT("Determinants Calculator"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
{
    wxStaticBoxSizer *matrix;
    wxFlexGridSizer *cells;
    wxBoxSizer *subBox;
    wxBoxSizer *mainBox;

    fileMenu = new wxMenu;
    helpMenu = new wxMenu;
    menuBar = new wxMenuBar();

    helpMenu->Append(wxID_ABOUT, wxT("&About"), wxT("Show about dialog"));
    fileMenu->Append(wxID_EXIT, wxT("&Exit"), wxT("Quit this program"));

    menuBar->Append(fileMenu, wxT("&File"));
    menuBar->Append(helpMenu, wxT("&Help"));

    td = new wxTextEntryDialog(this, wxT("Enter the number of dimensions: "), wxGetTextFromUserPromptStr, wxT("2"));
    td->ShowModal();
    SetMenuBar(menuBar);
    str = td->GetValue();
    n = wxAtoi(str);

    mainBox = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    MainPanel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    matrix = new wxStaticBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL, MainPanel, "Matrix: ");
    cells = new wxFlexGridSizer(0, n, 0, 0);
    subBox = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            numbers[i][j] = new wxTextCtrl(MainPanel, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(40,20), 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_TextCtrl"));
            cells->Add(numbers[i][j], 0, wxALL | wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
        }

    matrix->Add(cells, 1, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 2);
    subBox->Add(matrix, 1, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);

    wxBoxSizer *enb = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxBoxSizer *rnb = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxBoxSizer *bc = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

    Enter = new wxButton(MainPanel, ID_Calculate, _("Calculate"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_Calculate"));
    Reset = new wxButton(MainPanel, ID_Reset, _("Reset"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_Reset"));
    enb->Add(Enter, 1, wxALL |wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    rnb->Add(Reset, 1, wxALL |wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    bc->Add(enb, 0, wxALL | wxEXPAND);
    bc->Add(rnb, 0, wxALL | wxEXPAND);
    subBox->Add(bc, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL);
    MainPanel->SetSizer(subBox);
    mainBox->Add(MainPanel);
    mainBox->Fit(this);
    this->SetSizer(mainBox);
    CentreOnScreen();
}

void determinantsFrame::OnReset(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            numbers[i][j]->SetLabel(wxEmptyString);
}

void determinantsFrame::OnCalculateClick(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    double elem[MAX][MAX], det;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            elem[i][j] = static_cast<double>(wxAtoi(numbers[i][j]->GetValue()));

    det = determinant(elem, n);
    wxMessageBox(wxString::Format(wxT("%.2f"),det));
}

double determinantsFrame::determinant(double matrix[MAX][MAX], int order)
{
    double det = 0, temp[MAX][MAX]; int row, col;

    if (order == 1)
        return matrix[0][0];
    else if (order == 2)
        return ((matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1]) - (matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0]));
    else
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < order; r++)
        {
            col = 0; row = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < order; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < order; j++)
                {
                    if (j == r)
                        continue;

                    temp[row][col] = matrix[i][j];
                    col++;

                    if (col == order - 1)
                        col = 0;
                }
                row++;
            }
            det = det + (matrix[0][r] * pow(-1, r) * determinant(temp, order - 1));
        }
        return det;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `wxNewId()` which is a run-time function to initialize an ID used in compile-time event table macros. Either make the IDs real compile-time constants, or use `Bind()` instead of the event tables to connect the handlers at run-time too.

As an aside, calling `exit()` from `OnClose()` is quite wrong. I strongly recommend looking at wxWidgets samples to see how things are typically done. Better yet would be to read the docs to understand why are they done like this, but this could be a next step.

Comment: How do I make compile-time constants? Can you please explain further? I'm a newb in wxWidgets. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Typically using an enum. Please look at the samples, they will answer this question and many more.

Comment: Uhm, what examples? Can I have a link? I can't seem to find a good one on google.

Comment: Look in the `samples` directory of wxWidgets distribution you download or https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/samples/minimal/minimal.cpp and other samples nearby if you really need to view them online.